# Destroy a vampire by turning

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters

If you make a turning or greater turning check that would destroy a vampire is it destroyed? Description of vampire seems to say only way they are destroyed is sunlight or running water.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## This DM would rule that a [vampire](http://dndsrd.net/monstersTtoZ.html#vampire) *can* be destroyed by a [turn undead attempt](http://dndsrd.net/specialAttacks.html#turn) that would see the vampire destroyed

This DM considers the *Monster Manual* entry on Slaying a Vampire (253) to be the *general* ways a vampire can be destroyed; other *specific* ways a vampire can be destroyed need not be covered by Slaying a Vampire because those other methods can *already* destroy a vampire!

That is, if on Slaying a Vampire is read as an *exhaustive* list—as those being the *only* ways that a vampire can be destoyed—, a vampire that should've been obliterated by the 6th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*undeath to death*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsTtoZ.html#undeath-to-death) [necro] (*Player's Handbook* 297) would instead be unaffected, a vampire that should've been destroyed by a magic weapon that possesses the magic weapon special ability [*disruption*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsAW.html#disruption) (*Dungeon Master's Guide* 224) (+2 bonus; 0 lbs.) keeps right on sucking, and a vampire that should've been [destroyed by a turn undead attempt](http://dndsrd.net/specialAttacks.html#turn) sufficient to destroy any *other* undead creature of equivalent power continues to terrorize the frightened villagers scattered across the bleak, soggy moors.

Really, were that list totally exhaustive, even the 8th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*sunburst*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsS.html#sunburst) [evoc] (*PH* 289) that specifically says that "the [*sunburst* spell's] burst results in the destruction of any undead creature specifically harmed by bright light (such as a vampire) if it fail its save" would still *not* actually destroy a vampire. Read exhaustively, the vampire, after failing its save, would point to that Slaying a Vampire entry and say, "So what? *My* List of Dooms doesn't include *sunburst*."

In short, this DM is of the opinion that the many ways that a vampire can be slain include the ways in the Slaying a Vampire entry and *also* include the ways that a vampire can be dealt with due to, for example, a vampire possessing the type [undead](http://dndsrd.net/monsterTypes.html#undead).

Answer (score 14):

The rules text says:

> If reduced to 0 hit points in combat, it automatically assumes gaseous form and attempts to escape.
>
> Any additional damage dealt to a vampire forced into gaseous form has no effect.

"Destroying" a vampire is not the same as reducing it to 0 hit points.  Rules As Written, destroying a vampire using a turning check will actually destroy it.

Note that a vampire has +4 turn resistance.  Under most circumstances a vampire will have at least 5 HD, so it would take an 18HD turn check (or a 9HD greater turning check) to destroy even a low-level vampire in this way.